# How can I sum specific columns in a row, depending on another column?

Tags: python, aggregate, multiple-columns, rows

could you please help my with the following issue:

Sample File :

[image]

I try to aggregate the sum of 6 months, **up from a specific start date** per row.

The sum should be shown in a new column (Sum 6 months from startdate)

My first thought would be to get it with the following code:

```
df['sum_6_months'] = df.loc[:,'01.2018':'06.2018'].apply(sum, axis=1)
```

but this code is **not individually** and only for the timeframe (01.18-06.18) in all rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4,1], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7,8,2,5,7,3,4,2],[1,5,3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4],
                             [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4,3], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7,8,2,5,7,3,4,4],[1,5,5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4],
                             [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4,5], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7,8,2,5,7,3,4,5],[1,5,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4],
                             [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4,6], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7,8,2,5,7,3,4,2],[1,5,5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4],
                             [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4,4], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7,8,2,5,7,3,4,2],[1,5,1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,2,5,7,3,4]]),
                   columns=['01.2018', '02.2018', '03.2018', '04.2018', '05.2018','06.2018', '07.2018', '08.2018',
                            '09.2018','10.2018', '11.2018', '12.2018','01.2019', '02.2019', '03.2019'])

date = [01.2018, 03.2018,04.2018,05.2018,03.2018,01.2018, 03.2018,04.2018,05.2018,03.2018,01.2018, 03.2018,04.2018,05.2018,03.2018]
df['Startdate']= date
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I am sorry but this site has rules about what questions are acceptable and this one does not meet them. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. Here, as you only show a spreadsheet **image** instead of the content of a dataframe given as text, others cannot try their code on your data. Without some data that can be copied and pasted, this question is just *off topic* and likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Startdate']=df['Startdate'].astype(str).str.rjust(7,'0')

df_columns = df.columns.tolist()
def get_sum_six(df_list):
    start_date_index = df_columns.index(df_list[-1])
    df_list = df_list[0:-1]
    sum_of_six = sum(df_list[start_date_index: start_date_index + min(len(df_list)-start_date_index, 6)])
    return (sum_of_six)

df['sum_last_six'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_sum_six(x.tolist()), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Amazing

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the number of columns to skip in each row:

```
df2['StartCol'] = 1 + df2.columns[1:].searchsorted(df2.Startdate)
```

The `1:` skips the `Startdate` column.  Then "roll" that many columns to the left, so they wrap around and end up at the end of each row, take the first 6, and sum:

```
np.roll(df2.iloc[:, 1:], -df2.StartCol)[:,:6].sum(1)
```

That gives you:

```
[27, 28, 27, 21, 26, 27, 29, 27, 21, 25, 27, 25, 25, 18, 23]
```

Which you can store in a new column if you like.

Comment: John Zwinck, first of all thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help.
I got that you calculate in the first step, the first column from where it should sum up the values in the row. Then in the second step: 
With the the start from 1: you exclude the startmonth, correct?
and I think the output is not correct because for the first sum in row (index=0 / with Startdate 01.2018) it should give sum for those 6 months of 24 but you had 27. Do you have maybe an idea whats the issue in this case? Thanks a lot in advance!